# How to fix "Logical file X is not part of database Y..." while all names are correct

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When restoring a backup, I have an error:

> Logical file 'foo' is not part of database 'YY'. Use RESTORE
>   FILELISTONLY to list the logical file names.

The restore script work fine if I do `WITH FILE = 1` but it shows the error, if I do `WITH FILE = 2`.

I have run FILELISTONLY and name "foo" is really there and its correct.

I have run HEADERONLY and there are two items, and I need second one restored.

Actual script:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [ni_5] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\backup\ni_5.bak' WITH  FILE = 2 /* will work if i put 1 here*/,   NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10,
MOVE N'foo_dat' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ni_5.mdf',  
MOVE N'Fooind1' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_1.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind10' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_10.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind11' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_11.ndf', 
MOVE N'Fooind12' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_12.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind2' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_2.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind3' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_3.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind4' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_4.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind5' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_5.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind6' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_6.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind7' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_7.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind8' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_8.ndf',  
MOVE N'Fooind9' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_9.ndf',  
MOVE N'foo_log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\foo_13.ldf'


GO
```

Actual output:

```
Msg 3154, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'ni_5' database.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Comment: can you post your actual script?

Comment: @JohnJoseph posted

Comment: @RustemMustafin Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @AlbertoSolano yep, solved by requesting the correct back up. Apparently, the one I used initially was incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing
>   'ni_5' database.

This means that your `ni_5.bak` backup set contains a backup of database different from an already existing `ni_5` database.

> The restore script work fine if I do WITH FILE = 1 but it shows the
>   error, if I do WITH FILE = 2.

Considering the above error, this is perfectly reasonable because with `FILE = 2` you're basically saying that you want the 2nd backup, contained in your  `ni_5.bak` backup set, to be restored (that contains the correct database to be restored). This is fine on the basis of what you want and said:

> I need second one restored